# How can I transform the standard deviation after transforming (x, y) points?

Tags: python, statistics

I am plotting a set of (x, y) points. The blue bars are my error bars. I'm scaling my (x, y) points to be (x, y^2). I'm squaring my error bars by squaring them too. However, they seem tiny after squaring them.

My y values before squaring are on the magnitude of 10-20 while my error is ~0.1. Afterward, my y values become ~100-400 while my error bars are ~0.01. It seems strange my error would shrink while my y values would grow.

Am I doing this math correctly?

[image: (x, y) data not being squared][(x, y) data after being squared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2haA.png)

How can I scale error bars after squaring my y values?

Answer (score 1):

Well 0.1² is 0.01 while 10² (resp 20²) is 100 (resp 400). So it should not be surprising.

But the real problem is not that. It is that "the error of (y squared)" is not "(the error of y) squared".

(Y+ε)² = Y² + ε² + 2Yε

And the important part here is the 2Yε part (unless ε is bigger than 2Y, but then that would be that you have a huge noise/signal problem to begin with; and any way, you've said ε is around 0.1, when Y is around 10-20, so we are far from this case).

So if you really need to "scale" the error, when plotting Y², while not recomputing it (with whatever method you used to compute the error of Y in the first place), then, you should scale it by computing 2εY (so Y→Y², and ε→2Yε. Or even 2Yε+ε² if you wish, but that ε² is negligible, as you've already seen — that is even the reason for your question ; typical error, when Y=20, Y²=400, would be around 40×ε+ε² = 40×0.1+0.01 = 4.01, if ε is 0.1. `4` being the `2Yε` part, and and `.01` being the `ε²`. So, that `2Yε` is a really decent approximation)